# If there is no destruction of mass in the nuclear fission , then how is tremendous energy is released?

Tags: nuclear, nuclear-chemistry

In the fission of U-235 , calculate the mass of reactants , which are U-235 and 1 low energy neutrons .
hence , the mass in reactant is = 235 + 1 = 236amu (atomic mass unit).
Now , in the products , barium , krypton are formed and 3 neutrons are emitted .
Hence , mass of products is :
mass of krypton ( 139 amu) + mass of barium (94 amu) + mass of 3 neutrons ( 3 amu ) = 139 + 94 + 3 = 236 amu (atomic mass unit) .
From above , it is clear that mass of reactants = mass of products = 236 atomic mass units
Hence , no mass is destroyed in fission reaction . hence , no tremendous energy should be released .

Comment: There is no reason why a barium nucleus should be lighter than a krypton nucleus.

Comment: If you measure the mass of each particle (nuclei, neutrons etc.) very precisely (more decimal places), and do the math, you will see that there is a slight mass loss. That mass loss is converted to energy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is based on the false assumption that the mass of nucleus is equal the sum of masses of respective count of free protons and neutrons. So you erroneously identify the nucleon numbers with multiples of the atomic mass unit.

A mass of atomic nucleus is decreased, compared to the total proton and neutron mass, by the relativistic mass equivalent of binding energy of nucleons ( energy needed to break a nucleus to elementary particles).

$$m_{\mathrm{nucleus}}\  \lt Z \cdot m_\mathrm{p} + N \cdot m_\mathrm{n}$$

- $Z$ is the proton number
- $N$ is the neutron number
- $m_\mathrm{p}, m_\mathrm{n}$ is the proton respectively neutron  mass.

As this binding energy differs for various elements and their isotopes, the average mass per a constituent proton/nucleon is nucleus is not constant.

Therefore the mass of $\ce{^{20}_{10}Ne}$ is greater then a half of the mass of $\ce{^{40}_{20}Ca}$, as calcium nucleus has higher binding energy than neon . Similarly a nucleus $\ce{^4He}$ has by 0.7% less mass than the total mass of 2 protons and 2 neutrons, from which it consists.

During $\ce{^{235}U}$, the mass of the uranium nucleus is greater than the sum of masses of 2 created nuclei and 2-3 released neutrons.

See [Nuclear binding energy curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_binding_energy#Nuclear_binding_energy_curve).

Comment: you are expected to make a grade 10 student to understand this . please simplify the answer.

Comment: @anoman I was not expected to do so, as you omitted to mention it. Quality of answers reflects quality and completeness of questions.

Comment: @Maurice He rather identified the nucleon numbers with multiples of the atomic mass unit, what was wrong. The Ba and Kr specifics are just a particular extra mess, based on false premise.

Comment: $235$ for the mass of $\ce{U-235}$, he should have used $235.044$. And he should have used existing isotopes. For example Krypton-$139$ and Baryum-$94$ do not exist. Probably masses have been interchanged. Any way the calculations must be made with more precise masses.

Comment: It should be rather comment to the question.